# nvm install using git failed? Help interpreting this terminal message

Tags: git, nvm

I'm starting to get my feet wet with tools like Git, NVM, NPM, etc. I have made a few attempts to get started so far but keep running into roadblocks outside the scope of most tutorials.

So I was following the instructions for installation on npmjs.com, and the terminal result was the following

```
my-imac:~ myname$ curl -o-
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | 
bash
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  
Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  
Speed
100 12540  100 12540    0     0  87501      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:-
-:-- 87692
=> Downloading nvm from git to '/Users/mvallesillas/.nvm'
=> Cloning into '/Users/mvallesillas/.nvm'...
remote: Counting objects: 264, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (229/229), done.
remote: Total 264 (delta 31), reused 107 (delta 25), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (264/264), 116.46 KiB | 19.41 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (31/31), done.
Note: checking out '7ad6d98cedde01809e32d56ab8ced064f6f28175'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make 
experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in 
this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you             
may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again.         
Example:

git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

=> Compressing and cleaning up git repository

=> Profile not found. Tried ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, and 
~/.profile.
=> Create one of them and run this script again
OR
=> Append the following lines to the correct file yourself:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
npm ERR! invalid: minizlib@1.0.3             

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minizlib
=> You currently have modules installed globally with `npm`. These will no
=> longer be linked to the active version of Node when you install a new node
=> with `nvm`; and they may (depending on how you construct your `$PATH`)
=> override the binaries of modules installed with `nvm`:

/usr/local/lib
├── gulp-cli@1.3.0
=> If you wish to uninstall them at a later point (or re-install them under your
=> `nvm` Nodes), you can remove them from the system Node as follows:

$ nvm use system
$ npm uninstall -g a_module

=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Answer (score 0):

(nvm maintainer here)

It looks like your system installation of node/npm might be messed up and require reinstallation (which is outside of nvm). However, if you file an issue on the repo and fill out the template, i can help you in more detail.